# UTC timestamp in millisecond using C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

How do I get the UTC time in milliseconds under the Windows platform?

I am using the standard library which give me UTC time in seconds. I want to get the time in milliseconds. Is there a reference of another library which give me the accurate UTC time in milliseconds?

Comment: Check all the comments in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856265 - it looks like this has already been answered for you.

Comment: @Paul R, the question you linked to doesn't seem to be a duplicate at all.

Comment: @avakar: if you read the comments to the answers in the linked question it already gives the answer as to how to get UTC timestamps with ms resolution, hence Arman's new question is at least redundant, even if it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Paul R, I've looked at the answers on the page you linked to, but this question is not answered there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GetSystemTime() produces a UTC time stamp with millisecond resolution.  Accuracy however is far worse, the clock usually updates at 15.625 millisecond intervals on most Windows machines.  There isn't much point in chasing improved accuracy, any clock that provides an absolute time stamp is subject to drift.  You'd need dedicated hardware, usually a GPS radio clock, to get something better.  Which are hard to use properly on a non-realtime multi-tasking operating system.  Worst-case latency can be as much as 200 milliseconds.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`GetSystemTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function, or perhaps [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397%28VS.85%29.aspx) if you want a single number.